# Bootstrap columns are wrapping on mobile devices that should fit perfectly inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I have a bunch of `.col-xs-3` and `.col-xs-9` columns that should fit perfectly inline. They do on the desktop, even with media queries as narrow as 300px and below, but when I view the page on an actual mobile device (including the latest iPhone models), the columns wrap.

You can see my page here: https://affordable-healthcare-plans.org/p/signup-4.php

How it looks on desktops at small media queries (correct)
[image: https://i.imgur.com/BwbXmEO.png]

How it actually looks on mobile (incorrect)
[image: https://i.imgur.com/IYFOub8.jpg]

**What I've tried so far**

I've started on a workaround where I disable `flex-wrap: wrap` on the rows but that really shouldn't be necessary since the bootstrap sizes should be an exact match.

**EDIT**

I could link to the source but my issue is mainly that I'm using bootstrap with some custom CSS and I don't know where the issue is coming from. Looks fine for me on older models.

Some of my snippets:

```
.form-contain .col-md-6 .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```
.row > label {
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    left: -15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Adding `white-space: nowrap` doesn't bring the labels and fields inline either and that almost always works.

Comment: Add what you have done so far as an example and please [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @YashKaranke added some more context and info on what I've tried so far

Comment: Please read [Minimal, Complete, Variable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which means a snippet of code which you're trying and what you want to accomplish from the question

Comment: We will need the HTML and CSS to address the issue.  I pulled it up on my phone and ran it though dev tools and even on Iphone 5 and it looks fine to me.

Comment: @KJEK-Code see edits

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell Post your HTML/CSS/JS or whatever part of the code you think there is an error, post it in the question

Comment: if you do not want the item to wrap it should be flex-wrap: nowrap or remove flex-wrap all together (as nowrap is the default) More here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp

Comment: @KJEK-Code but `flex-wrap: wrap` should only wrap when the contents overflow from the container, and a `.col-xs-3` and `.col-xs-9` shouldn't overflow at all. Added some code that could be relevant to my original post

Comment: I understand that but if you never want the items to wrap then why would you add flex-wrap at all if they "shouldn't overflow at all"?

Comment: If nothing else, it helps to diagnose that there is, in fact, an issue.

Comment: More importantly, there is a row with more than 1 inline field, and when I set flex-wrap to nowrap, that one breaks even more and attampts to squish everything onto one line that I do want to wrap in that case.

If Bootstrap column wrapping was properly working, it'd work in both case. Such a strange issue

Comment: I have seen safari and IOS have issues with flex-wrap before but I am not sure what exactly it is.  I cannot get your site to wrap no matter what I do.  I can see your state and zip get thrown off when flex wrap is disabled.  Not sure past that, good luck

Comment: Issue solved! Posting solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved! Bootstrap was placing a 0x0 px `display: table` pseudo-element via `::before` inside each row, and somehow although it should have no size, it was causing the columns to wrap. Forced that pseudo to `display: none` within my form and now everything displays properly.